# Is there a way to switch Android users from the command line?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, lock-screens, command-line, multi-user

Using the following command, I managed to enable multi-user mode in an Android device that doesn't officicially support it: `adb shell setprop fw.max_users 5`. For good measure I also added the following entry to the `build.prop` file:

```
fw.max_users=5
```

There's now a Settings menu for creating additional users in my device. Upon creating a new user, I would be switched to the multi-user lock screen with icons at the bottom showing the user accounts available in the device. From there I can choose my user log-in.

Moreover, the account data of the new user survives a reboot. From this, I can conclude that multi-user mode is working.

The problem is my Android device, a media player running some version of Jellybean 4.2, normally doesn't display the lock screen. No lock screen appears when I start up the device nor after I suspend or put the device to sleep.

In fact, the only time I see the lockscreen is immediately after creating a new user. Once I've logged in as the new user, I can't switch back to the lock screen because the device is configured to show only the bottom panel and therefore I have no way to click the User icon in the Quick Settings menu of the missing top panel.

It seems a bit overkill to do some low-level system hacks just to achieve the desktop Linux equivalent of Control-Alt-F8, etc. Is there a command, perhaps using some intent or activity available via the Android activity manager tool (`am`) that would allow me to switch between different user log-ins or at least to switch to the lock screen that would allow me to log in as a different user?

Comment: Just a raw idea: could it help to toggle keyguard for that (which is responsible for "locking" the device)? If so, that could be done using e.g. *Tasker*, and you could create a shortcut to that task on your homescreen: touch that, switch screen off, then on again, and you should be presented with a lock screen – where you hopefully could switch users, and then use the shortcut to toggle keyguard off again. If that works for you, and you consider it a "valid answer", let me know and I will make it one :)

Answer (score 30):

**Yes there is.**
When the community discovered this feature in android 4.1 (the code was exist but has not been declared yet so Google did not open the feature in Settings), I remember playing with this in my Nexus 4.

So, here are some commands that I remember for the android Terminal:

- Create new user: `pm create-user User_Name`
- To switch between users: `am switch-user User_ID`
- To get the list of all the users: `pm list users`
- To delete a user: `pm remove-user User_ID`

Hope this helps.