# How to set restricted user as default user on reboot?

Tags: reboot, restricted-profiles

We would like to have an already added restricted user account be the default when we restart our Samsung SM-T580 tablets.

At current we have 2 accounts installed, Admin and User
The User is a user with restricted access.

The tablets are rooted

Hope that someone has a solution for our question

Answer (score 3):

I am suggesting two solutions. Both of them require root access, and both were tested on a OnePlus 6 running Android 10.

## Solution #1

Have the following script (let's call it *switch-user.sh*) run during boot but after the user has entered device decryption credentials (PIN/password)

```
#!/system/bin/sh

while true; do
        flag=`/system/bin/getprop vold.fbe.decrypted`
        if [ $flag ]; then
                sleep 1;
                /system/bin/am switch-user USER_ID          # replace USER_ID term with restricted user's id
                exit;
        else 
                sleep 1;
        fi
done
```

What this script does is to continuously check (with a delay of 1 second) whether the user has decrypted the device or not. If yes, switch to the restricted user after one second, or continue to recheck. Since my restricted user's User Id is `10`, I used 10 as `USER_ID` in it. Change it to whatever User Id your restricted user has. See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123209/96277) if you need help in finding out the User Id.

**Note**: In the above script I am checking for the value of the property `vold.fbe.decrypted` which works for my OnePlus 6 running Android 10. Your device may or may not have the same property. You can hunt for the relevant property by looking into the output of the command `adb shell 'getprop | grep vold'`. Alternatively, see if `sys.user.0.ce_available` property is available in your Android version.

Next thing to do is to put that script into a location in your Android from where the system would execute it on its own during boot. Since I use Magisk, I placed that *switch-user.sh* script into the directory `/data/adb/service.d` (see Magisk's [Boot Scripts](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#boot-scripts) section for further information on it) and **added executable permission to it** using the command:

```
adb shell su -c 'chmod +x /data/adb/service.d/switch-user.sh'
```

If you do not use Magisk, you can take the help from the answers at [How can I run a script on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/6558)

Restart the device to see if your script works. In my case, whenever I enter my PIN to decrypt the device, than within two-three seconds the system automatically switches to my restricted user.

---

## Solution #2

If you don't want the hassle of injecting a script into boot process you can setup an automation app which would switch the Android to your restricted user once it receives BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast, or in other words, do something during startup.

I can suggest [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) as I have tried them and they worked on Genymotion with Android 6.0 and on a OnePlus 6 with Android 10. You can try any app which can run a command/script on startup.

### Tasker

For Tasker, the profile and the task should be this:

**Profile**: *Event → Device Boot*

**Task**: *Code → Run Shell:*

- *Command*: `su 2000 -c am switch-user USER_ID`
- tick *Use Root*
- leave the rest of the settings untouched

Make sure to replace `USER_ID` there with the actual user id of the restricted user.

### MacroDroid

For MacroDroid, the Macro should be this:

**Trigger**: *Device Events → Device Boot*

**Action**: *Applications → Shell Script:*

- tick *Rooted*
- Enter the following command in "*Enter script*" field: `su 2000 -c am switch-user USER_ID`
- leave the rest of the settings untouched

Make sure to replace `USER_ID` there with the actual user id of the restricted user. See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123209/96277) if you need help in finding out the User Id.

**Note:** because many apps would be competing to run their XYZ things during startup, you might notice a delay of a couple of seconds before user switching takes place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add an App that will start at every system start to switch to a secondary user. The method require a version of Android 10 minimum.

Let's suppose that the secondary user is not admin and it's the only secondary user.

### Source code:

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.switchuser">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.switchuser.BootReceiver"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".AppAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**res/xml/device_admin_receiver.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
        <disable-keyguard-features />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.switchuser;

import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.UserHandle;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int RESULT_ENABLE = 11;
    private ComponentName compName;
    private DevicePolicyManager manager;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        compName = new ComponentName(this, AppAdminReceiver.class);

        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, compName);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Explain why we need this permission");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);

        manager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        # Get list of secondary users
        List<UserHandle> listUsers = manager.getSecondaryUsers(compName);
        
        #Switch to the first secondary user in the list
        manager.switchUser(compName, listUsers.get(0));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AppAdminReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.switchuser;

import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class AppAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "AppAdminReceiver";
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onProfileProvisioningComplete(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Enable the profile
        DevicePolicyManager manager =
                (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        ComponentName componentName = this.getComponentName(context);

        manager.setProfileName(componentName, "SwitchUser");

        manager.setLockTaskPackages(componentName, new String[]{"com.example.switchuser"});
    }

    /**
     * @return A newly instantiated {@link ComponentName} for this
     * DeviceAdminReceiver.
     */
    public static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context) {
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), AppAdminReceiver.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin : enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin : disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.switchuser;

import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.UserHandle;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.util.List;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Boot Receiver";
    private ComponentName compName;
    private DevicePolicyManager manager;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

                compName = new ComponentName(context, AppAdminReceiver.class);


                manager = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

                List<UserHandle> listUsers = manager.getSecondaryUsers(compName);

                manager.switchUser(compName, listUsers.get(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To enable the application as Device Owner in order have permissions to change the user, we need to use ADB:

```
adb root
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.example.switchuser/.AppAdminReceiver
```

## User restriction

In order to harden the user you can:

1. Dump `/data/system/users/10.xml` where 10 is the id of the user. The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<user id="10" serialNumber="10" flags="16" created="1598034338552" lastLoggedIn="1598035769294" lastLoggedInFingerprint="Android/sdk_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:10/QPP6.190730.005.B1/5775370:userdebug/test-keys" icon="/data/system/users/10/photo.png" profileBadge="0">
    <name>New user</name>
    <restrictions no_sms="true" no_outgoing_calls="true" />
</user>
```

2. Add more restrictions. The list of restrictions can be founded on [UserManager Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager)
3. push the changes

```
adb push 10.xml /data/system/users/10.xml
```

## Reboot

Once the device start the application switch the user to the secondary user.

## Tests

The app was tested on AVD (Android Virtual Device)

[Source code on github](https://github.com/SecTheTech/SwitchUserBoot)

Comment: Hi! I appreciate the source code for the app, but considering Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange focuses on Android end-users (but not necessarily developers), I'm afraid this answer is a bit too much for the majority of end-users and out-of-scope of this site. Considering that the source code is already on GitHub, I'd suggest removing the source code and providing the link to the APK instead so that non-dev end-users can use it directly, and dev-users can still build it from GitHub if they want. Thanks!