# Need to lock Genymotion SaaS appliance to run only 1 app in restricted user by default and prevent install 3rd party apps and access to settings

Tags: genymotion, restricted-profiles

(solved)

I need to run an app in Genymotion that is used for data entry and upload of the entered data into 3rd party sites. The logins to 3rd party sites are stored in this application (probably encrypted). The application will store multiple logins for my different customers of who need to have the data uploaded into the 3rd party sites. The data into the app will then be entered by other people to whom I outsource the data entry.

So I created Genymotion appliance, installed the app and in this application I entered logins for sites such as ebay. I am looking for suggestions on what can I do to secure the appliance to prevent the data being copied out from it.

I want to prevent the person to whom I outsource data entry to be able to install and load 3rd party other apps, modify system settings, install other apps, copy the system directory, copy the login and password information saved by the application.

Let's assume the worst possible case here when application is well written but the passwords mentioned above (for the ecommerce sites like ebay) is saved in plain text in this application in the internal application directory. What I know about the application is it doesn't support access to SD Card, only can read and write data to the internal memory.

What can I do in Gennymotion to improve the security of my appliance. Genymotion virtual machines are rooted. So I looked at following steps already:

1. Setup restricted user on Android
2. Set restriction for the restricted user to only be able to use the one application. Disable anything else (including disabled browser, email, youtube etc..)
3. Try to get the restricted user loading on boot of Android. When Android restarts, however, it doesn't allow choice to login into the restricted user or the admin user, sort of like a Windows or MacOS login menu. To get the appliance to always start with restricted user by default, I need to add a script and the scripted will need to start using Tasker or MacroDroid.

However, how do I prevent the user from installing 3rd party apps? Is it good enough to disable all user apps (except that one used for data entry) from the restricted user? Is there any other way the user could abuse the access to the virtual appliance and load something there? Are there any system android apps I need to disable for the restricted user to prevent the user to be able to do anything bad with it?

The application used for data entry can not download any application or data, however, I believe it does use the webview because it loads sites like ebay and fills the forms on those sites. It only interacts with select websites only like Ebay to enter data into Ebay forms..

Is there anything I can do to secure Genymotion appliance any other than what I already mentioned. I would like to send the link to the Genymotion SaaS Android to people who will do data entry for me into Ebay and other sites. So I need to make sure the virtual appliance is secured as much as possible from tinkering with it. I need to make sure somebody doesn't get hand on the stored login details.

Just to clarify for the login credentials:

I am not sure how the user credentials are stored and I will find it out, however, for now, I go from the worst case scenario when the credentials are stored in plain text in the app settings. The user name and password is stored in the application with exception for Ebay because the many other sites do not have API key or any webservices interface, so the application would access those sites simply via a webview, and when it goes to login there it will do that by filling in the login information on the login form (simulates keystrokes). The user name and password is entered into the login form for the site. That's why the login info is stored in the application itself.

This question is not about how to secure the specific application I will be using, but how to secure the actual whole Android appliance from tinkering with.

I am aware I will the risks here, just want to do as much due diligence as I can.

Update:

Done some digging so this cannot be done. Neither Genymobile or Appetize or other online Android emulators can offer fine-tuning in terms of user access. The closest is Genymobile because at least allows adding and removing access of users to individual appliances. That is however not resolving the issue with Android and in particular rooted Android, since all online emulators run rooted Android and I am not sure how that is secured against potentially malicious actors who receive access link.

The only easy way to solve it, kind of in a mickey-mousy way is to install Kiosk mode application. That kiosk app will run at every boot and it only shows the specific application. There is always risk of course the malicious user would do something to crash the application and the Kiosk app, but if the application is not a web browser or email client or similar it should be relatively safe.

There are plenty of Kiosk mode apps for Android but none of them is free (don't try to look, no chance to find one), the cheapest cost about 7 USD one-time purchase, the more expensive ones cost 20 per month per device or more and come with remote control etc... Not cheap but kiosk mode apps are almost exlusively used by businesses so that's why there is lack of free apps.

Anyhow I believe this is the closest as I could get to deal with this.

---

Sources for Genymotion restricted user setup ..

[How to set restricted user as default user on reboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176827/how-to-set-restricted-user-as-default-user-on-reboot)

https://docs.genymotion.com/paas/10_Using_root_access/

Comment: Genymotion is an emulator that is installed on  local PC. It is based on VirtualBox so you have an Open Source emulator running on a PC the user may have admin/root permissions. **Thus no matter what you do the user can modify everything and every limitation you implement can by bypassed.** If you want to limit something you need to run everything on a server where you are the only one who has root access. But in general using an app in n emulator for data entering is a bad idea. better develop a website based on Python or PHP (server side execution).

Comment: Thanks for response. Sorry I didn't explain perhaps clearly. 1.  I am not using Genymotion desktop, but their SaaS product, which is server hosted on Genymotion server for which I pay subscription by minute. 2. I am already using Airtable for manual data entry collection and then it goes to the Android App. From there the Android app is entering data into Ebay/Amazon etc.  So did you mean develop website to enter data into Amazon/Ebay?

Comment: Resolved by installing Kiosk mode app on Android. Details in the original post.

Comment: Looks like you found a solution by yourself, which is great! Since this site is a Q&A site, consider [posting it as a proper answer instead](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) since it's encouraged by the site, thanks!