# is there a common symlink in android multi-users, access use's `root directory` ？

Tags: stock-android, storage, file-system, multi-user

On test tablet.
There are two users:

- `/storage/emulated/0/AAA`  --onwer
- `/storage/emulated/10/AAA`  --nomal user

My attempt:

1. `adb shell "ls -l /storage/emulated/legacy/AAA"` file dot exist.  **--failed**
2. `adb shell "dumpsys activity | grep -E "mUserLru" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+\]$" | tr -d "]""`  find the current user_id     `e.g.: 10`.
   Splice string the path `string.Format("/storage/emulated/{0}/AAA","10")`.  **--succeed ,but it's too complicated.**

I want to find a simple way.
like a common `symlink` or `adb command`,
When different users log in, can use the same method to access different `root directory`.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have already figured out that the path to user's home directory is `/storage/emulated/USER_ID/`. In order to find the user id of the the currently running user, follow my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123209/96277). I have updated it along the lines of Android Oreo.

Comment: Thanks.  I just read your answer ,then I found the user's link rule. In my opinion, there should be an android API . Different users `root directory` , the same simple way to access it. Now, it seems that there is no this way.