# How to change user account with Tasker?

Tags: tasker

Is there way to change user account with tasker?

Comment: Do you mean to switch "user accounts"? Which Android version are you using?

Comment: Yes. I updated question to be more specyfic.

Comment: It is still not clear what exactly to you want tasker to do: Do you want it to run tasks as a different user, or do you want a task which, when executed, changes the currently active user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need root access for this answer to work.

Setup this action in a task:

Code → Run Shell → 
Command: `am switch-user USER_ID`, 
tick Use Root

To know the USER_ID of a user account, see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123209/96277).