# Can you launch an application/activity of a different user with Tasker?

Tags: applications, tasker, multi-user

A follow up to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204661/209414) or [another related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73418169).

I am currently testing something related to file syncing, and I need to start an application/activity of an application installed in the secondary userspace. I want to launch that application/activity whilst I'm in the primary space (primary user) on demand. I thought Tasker could achieve this but am not sure how. I am somehow currently stuck, anyone who knows how to achieve this?

Something like: `am start -n packagename/.activityname`   but for the secondary user.

Comment: "Some restrictions exist when a secondary user is in background. For instance, the background secondary user cannot display the user interface..."  Source: [Multi-user system behavior](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multi-user#effects)