# Where is Google's internal account authentication token located?

Tags: root-access, google, tasker, authentication

I'm trying to write a Tasker script for my (rooted) phone that uses the same Google credentials that are being used on my device (for Gmail, Drive, etc.).

Where can I find Google's OAuth (or other) authentication tokens on my device?

I checked inside `/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases` but couldn't find anything I could recognize as an authentication token.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The authentication token for Google accounts and of other accounts which uses [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class are stored inside:

```
/data/system/users/0/accounts.db   # for Android Marshmallow and earlier
/data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db   # for Android Nougat and above.
```

`0` implies primary user of the device. If you have secondary user accounts, replace 0 with the user id of that account. To find out the user id follow my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/123209).

Note that access to that database requires root access.

Comment: **For anyone else interested:** Here's a command that will get you a token that has access to both Gmail and Google Drive (you need `sqlite3`): `su -c 'uid="$(/system/bin/readlink -f /storage/self/primary | /system/bin/grep -E -o "[0-9]+")"; "${PREFIX}/bin/sqlite3" -readonly "/data/system_ce/${uid-0}/accounts_ce.db" '"\"SELECT authtoken FROM authtokens WHERE type LIKE 'com.google.android.gm:%:oauth2:%https://mail.google.com/ %https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive %' ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1;\""`

Comment: @Mehrdad `$uid` will always be `0` if `su` switches to root mount namesapce, depends on configuration in root manager app. Also debug builds (most custom ROMs) already have `/system/bin/sqlite3`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif: Oh I see. I actually realized `/system/bin/readlink -f /storage/self/primary | /system/bin/grep -E -o \"[0-9]+\"` is faster so that's what I'm doing now. Sadly my ROM doesn't have `sqlite3` so that one's not an option for me, but thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad if you are using Magisk you can download the sqlite module to get access to sqlite3 binary.